# python objects references and deep copy

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference

I'm a little bit confused all of a sudden, I may be tired now so that may be the reason.

Anyway consider the following using interpreter:

```
> x = {'hello':'world'}
> y=x

> x= None

>y
y={'hello':'world'}
```

Why not `y = None` isn't `y` now referencing the same value like x after the change?

Second question:
What is the difference between:

```
x= {'test':1}
y = dict(x)
VS  
y = copy.deepcopy(x)
```

Comment: `y` does not point to `x` it points to `x`'s data ... if you point `x` elsewhere, `y` is not influenced by it. - try `x["hello"] =  42` and evaluate `y`.

Comment: `y` is referencing the same value as `x` *had originally*. Then you rebound `x` to something else, but this does not affect `y`. Your `deepcopy` example isn't terribly useful since you can't really see the difference using non-mutable types like `str` or `int`. Try to use `x = {'test': [1,2,3]}` and try to manipulate the values and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the dictionary object `{'hello': 'world'}` is created in memory and then `x` is assigned as a reference to it.  Assigning `y=x` assigns a **second** reference to the dictionary object, this time to `y`.

However, `y` is NOT a pointer to the pointer of `x`.  Reassigning `x` doesn't change what `y` is referenced to.

---

For your second question, in this specific case, there is no difference.

Using:

```
x = {'test':1}
y = dict(x)
```

Creates a new copy of the dictionary and assigns it to `y`.

Using:

```
y = copy.deepcopy(x)
```

Creates an identical copy.  Where you would see a difference is when the value of the dictionary was a mutable object like a list.

Here, `y` is a shallow copy of `x`:

```
x = {'test': [1,2,3]}
y = dict(x)
```

So changing the list inside of the dictionary object referenced by `x` will also appear in `y` as well.

```
x['test'][1] = 0
y
# returns:
{'test': [1, 0, 3]}
```

However, using:

```
x = {'test': [1,2,3]}
y = copy.deepcopy(x)
```

will create a copy of the primary object as well as all of the objects it contains as well.  So now modifying the list in `x` will not change the value of `y`.

```
x['test'][1] = 0
y
# returns
{'test': [1,2,3]}
```